# CSS3: Hover effect with opacity on div's and text

Tags: css, css-transitions, opacity, css-transforms

I can't share a page on this, due to the page not being public. However, what I'm trying to do is create a hover effect on both a div and a H4 text element. Nothing of which seems to work for me. Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="grid__item small--one-half medium-up--one-quarter">
  <a href="/collections/hoop-earrings" class="collection-item collection-item--overlaid" data-aos="row-of-4"><div class="image-wrap">
        <div class="collection-image collection-image--square lazyload" style='background-position: center center; background-image: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1810/9951/collections/LDE42DSOS_Hexagon_Hoop_Earring_web_scroll_1200x_ad647924-a6b9-4c9a-b36a-7d6a3b0d0a6c_720x.jpg?v=1561755337");'>
        </div>
      </div>
      <noscript>
        <div
          class="collection-image collection-image--square"
          style="background-image: url(//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1810/9951/collections/LDE42DSOS_Hexagon_Hoop_Earring_web_scroll_1200x_ad647924-a6b9-4c9a-b36a-7d6a3b0d0a6c_400x.jpg?v=1561755337); background-position: center center;">
        </div>
      </noscript>
<div class="collection-image--overlay-background"></div>
    <span
  class="collection-item__title collection-item__title--overlaid collection-item__title--heading collection-item__title--center">
      <span>
        Text Goes Here
      </span>
    </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.collection-image--overlay-background {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s linear;
     transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
.collection-item__title.collection-item__title--overlaid.collection-item__title--heading.collection-item__title--center {
    opacity: 0!important;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s linear;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity .25s linear;
    transition: opacity .25s linear;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .collection-image--overlay-background:hover {
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: .8;
 }
 .collection-item__title.collection-item__title--overlaid.collection-item__title--heading.collection-item__title--center:hover {
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 1;
}
}
```

Comment: The part where you are using !important for your opacity in .collection-item__title. might cause you trouble.

Comment: also, you shouldn't be using !important if you're using BEM

Comment: I had to use !important. Otherwise, the test would not be transparent.

Answer (score 0):

I tried making a small snippet. See if it´s what you´re looking for.

Since you´re using the !important flag in one of your opacity rules, all the other changes after the fact will not take effect unless you also use !important. However I would not advice using !important that freely because whenever they are present such errors are a bit harder to track.

```css
.container {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
}

.onHover {
  background-color: red;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  opacity: 0.5;
  /*opacity: 0.5 !important; In your code you have
  a line like this.*/
}

.onHover:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="onHover">
    <h4>My title Here</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Finally got it working. It was both a z-index issue (both were using 1) and combining the overlay and text into one div so the text appears throughout the entire div. Not just part of it. Thanks for the help.